# Google Classroom iOS Share Button?

Tags: google-classroom

Is there an API to add a google classroom share button in iOS? I only see a Javascript example on the guides, and the iOS API doesn't say anything about a share button.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think share button is available on ios, but you can probably recreate something similar using a webview.

Answer (score 0):

There's no iOS SDK, but you can use URLs of the form https://classroom.google.com/share?url=https://foo.com/ to share content. (Using the system browser might work better than a WebView because the user is more likely to be logged in there.)

Comment: The linked blog post shows an example URL as `https://classroom.google.com/share?url=https://foo.com/`, but `https://foo.com/` should probably be encoded/escaped.

Comment: @NealGokli Is there a way to share image to Google classroom like this?

Comment: @isuru Sorry, I don't know.  I haven't touched Google Classroom (or software development) in a few years!